# How to make existing \strut-based code work with accented letters?

Tags: tex-core, line-spacing

`\strut`-based solutions assume that heights cannot exceed 8.5 pt and depth - 3.5 pt.
But with accented letters this assumption is not true. In the second example the last line is lower
than in the first example. How to make the baselines the same in both examples without changing the
main macro?

Example 1:

```
\input template
\font\tenrm=rm-lmr10 \tenrm
\marginalstar
X
\char'101
\bye
```

Example 2:

```
\input template
\font\tenrm=rm-lmr10 \tenrm
\marginalstar
X
\char'200
\bye
```

template.tex:

```
\def\marginalstar{\strut\vadjust{\kern-\dp\strutbox\smash{\llap{* }}\kern\dp\strutbox}}
\nopagenumbers
\hsize1em
\emergencystretch=1em
\noindent
```

If there does not exist a workaround so that existing code would work with accented letters, what guidelines should be followed in writing new code? Are \strut-based solutions bad and how to avoid them? How to make so that in all cases where `\strut` would be used, it was possible to do without it? (for example - to draw rules in tables; page 82 of TeXbook gives another example)

**EDIT**
Two more examples to illustrate the point. In the second example the right border is torn.

Example 3:

```
\font\tenrm=rm-lmr10 \tenrm
\hsize=5em
\hrule
\settabs 2 \columns
\+ \strut\vrule\hfill W\hfill\vrule& \hfill X \hfill\strut\vrule&\cr
\hrule
\+ \strut\vrule\hfill \char'101\hfill\vrule& \hfill Z \hfill\strut\vrule&\cr
\hrule
\bye
```

Example 4:

```
\font\tenrm=rm-lmr10 \tenrm
\hsize=5em
\hrule
\settabs 2 \columns
\+ \strut\vrule\hfill W\hfill\vrule& \hfill X \hfill\strut\vrule&\cr
\hrule
\+ \strut\vrule\hfill \char'200\hfill\vrule& \hfill Z \hfill\strut\vrule&\cr
\hrule
\bye
```

So according to @David Carlisle it should be:

```
\setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height9.5pt depth2.5pt width0pt}
```

Because:

```
$ tftopl rm-lmr10|grep CHARHT|sort|tail -n1
   (CHARHT R 0.9205)
$ tftopl rm-lmr10|grep CHARDP|sort|tail -n1
   (CHARDP R 0.25)
```

Right?

Comment: yes if in fact your height/depth do fit  in 12pt then 9.5/2.5 sounds good but note you may have other things in the line such as `$x_2$` so in some cases you may need a depth of more than 2.5 but so be it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\strut` is not a built in command it is simply

```
  \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height8.5pt depth3.5pt width\z@}
  \def\strut{\relax\ifmmode\copy\strutbox\else\unhcopy\strutbox\fi}
```

which is designed to fit 10pt computer modern English text set on a 12pt baseline.

If you have any other type of text you need to adjust `\strutbox` to have suitable height and depth,

In this case you get  `\lineskip` of 1pt between the lines as the accented A is 9.20499pt high an the `\strut` is 3.5pt deep so they can not fit on a 12pt baselineskip.

You probably need to change the baselineskip to say 12.5pt and adjust the strut to be 9.3 high and 3.2 deep or some such, or you could try to squeeze it in to 12pt with a strut 9.2 high and 2.8 deep

---

to address the questions in comments in latex you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}


\showoutput
\expandafter\show\the\font
\sbox0{Ă \v{A}\c{c}g(Q)$\sum_0^n(x)_7^n$}
\typeout{\the\ht0+\the\dp0=\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}
\usebox{0}


\end{document}
```

which shows that latex/plain tex isn't really the issue it is the font choice. Using ec fonts as above, it looks like you can just get away with a strut of 9pt high and 3pt deep which isn't quite what you get from latex which resets it after every size change to

```
    \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
      \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
            \@depth.3\baselineskip
            \@width\z@}%
```

so for a 12pt baseline that's 8.4pt+3.6pt  but you could redefine `\set@fontsize` to use .75 and .25 as the multipliers if you have a lot of accented capitals and no large descenders in the font.

Comment: I added some more examples to the question. Does LaTeX use `\strut` or there are other approaches?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko yes latex uses `\strut` and every font size command resets the strutbox accordingly, but `\strut` is not really the issue. If you need to set text that has 3.5pt descenders and 9.5pt high accented capitals then it does not fit in a 12pt baseline and changing `\strut` does not change that.

Comment: Does LaTeX support accented letters by default? Where in the LaTeX source is the definition of default `\strut`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko it depends what you mean by support and default, commands such as `\^` are defined in the format and the base latex distribution includes `inputenc` package that allows accented letters in a range of input encodings such as latin1 and utf8. `\strut` is defined on latex.ltx line 588 (Identical to plain definition)

Comment: By "default" I mean that when I type for example `Ă`, in the pdf output I get proper utf-8 symbol `Ă` (not composed of accents), copyable and searchable. Also, after compiling `\offinterlineskip \strut Ă \hrule \strut Ă \bye`, the distance between baselines must be 12pt. Will this work in LaTeX by default (i.e., without additional configuration)? And if not, what configuration must be done to work as described?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko you can't type `hello` in latex without inputting some extra macros first such as `\documentclass{article}` (which is (`\input article.cls`) so "default" and "without additional configuration" don't really make sense in that context.

Comment: Let it be instead of "without additional configuration" this: "with minimum required configuration". So, will this document with accented letters : `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\offinterlineskip \strut Ă \hrule \strut Ă\end{document}` work with normal non-accented pdf and interlineskip of 12pt? If not, what else should be done to make it work like this?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko see updated answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle shouldn't arguably package `fontenc`  patch `LaTeX` in order for `\strutbox` (and `\baselineskip`) to be defined in order for characters do not cause shifted baselines? the current situation sounds a bit unfortunate in view of the effort core `TeX` makes into placing lines `\baselineskip` apart if possible. I recall the matter was discussed two or three years ago [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/fr.comp.text.tex/NJKInAbqf10/discussion) on `f.c.t.tex` and seasoned `LaTeX` users were very surprised when they became aware that the problem was even more acute with `lmodern`.

Comment: @jfbu possibly not (reasons for not include stability but also the fact that at the point strut is used you don't know which fonts are going to be used in the line. The .7/.3 split is only ever a "best guess" and the idea was that someone setting up a class using non standard fonts would set an appropriate baseline. with lm you are close to it not fitting in a 12pt baseline but you may wish not to increase the baselineskip as almost always a large descender will not clash with large ascender on the next line. You need to make aesthetic judgement and package defaults are not the place for that,

Comment: @David Carlisle  the `0.7/0.3` rule, IIRC, causes a problem when a `\strut` is used in a line with simultaneously highest ascender and lowest descender in `12pt lmodern` (forgot the details), perhaps this is more a question of having this issue discussed in LaTeX guides, perhaps some `\adjustdefaultstrutstothisfont` could be useful.

Comment: @jfbu yes it will, although latex doesn't use struts much, just in footnotes and tables, more or less.

Comment: @jfbu: Knuth had to foresee this, because accents in CM-fonts were also higher than 8.5pt: `\setbox0=\hbox{\accent21 A} \showbox0` gives `\hbox(9.47221+0.0)x7.50002`. So how he himself handled such cases in his manuscripts?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko It is hardly ever a problem, it just means that if you have a tall accented capital on a line below a large descender then baselineskip will not be preserved and (as in one of your questions the other day) `\lineskip` will be used instead. But if writing in English this is almost certain not to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Update adds a patch of LaTeX's `\selectfont` to modify its way of defining `\strutbox` as per OP's request in a comment. To be further adapted to one's needs. When `\set@fontsize` is called, the new font isn't yet loaded, thus, I ended up adding some extra code at the very end of `\selectfont` rather than patching `\set@fontsize`.

---

`TeX` has a mechanism for setting lines `\baselineskip` apart which most of the time works fine. As explained in @DavidCarlisle's answer, the `\strutbox` is defined with an ad hoc `.7:.3:1` rule for `height:depth:baselineskip`. Unfortunately this means that adding a `\strut` to a situation where things were otherwise well aligned will sometimes cause misalignments. Here below is an example where the depth coming from the strut plus the height coming from an accented character on the next line will have a total exceeding the baselineskip, because the `.7\baselineskip` falls short of the height of the accented character.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage {multicol}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}\thispagestyle{empty}

Without struts:
\begin{multicols}{2}
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit\par
\columnbreak
\'Etat de droit \'Etat de droit \'Etat de droit \'Etat de droit \'Etat
de droit \'Etat de droit \'Etat de droit\par
\end{multicols}

With two added struts (the one on the left does no harm), the 
alignment is off!:

\begin{multicols}{2}
\strut Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit\par
\columnbreak
\strut État de droit État de droit État de droit État de droit État
de droit État de droit État de droit\par
\end{multicols}   
\end{document}
```

produces

> [image: Blockquote]

This was discussed in a thread on a French newsgroup, the situation is worse with `lmodern`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}\thispagestyle{empty}

Without struts:
\begin{multicols}{2}
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit\par
\columnbreak
\'Etat de droit \'Etat de droit \'Etat de droit \'Etat de droit \'Etat
de droit \'Etat de droit \'Etat de droit\par
\end{multicols}

With two added struts (the one on the left does no harm), the 
alignment is off!:

\begin{multicols}{2}
\strut Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit\par
\columnbreak
\strut État de droit État de droit État de droit État de droit État
de droit État de droit État de droit\par
\end{multicols}    

With more struts at the right, alignment even more off:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\strut Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit\par
\columnbreak
\strut État de droit État de droit État de droit \strut État de droit État
de droit État de droit État de droit\par
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

---

Code for patching `\selectfont`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% patch \selectfont
\makeatletter
\newbox\igor@tempbox
% or \@tempboxa but perhaps some code calls \selectfont
% not expecting \@tempboxa to be modified

\def\igor@fixstrutbox{\setbox\igor@tempbox\hbox{ÉÈÙÀĂÅ}% 
% first we reset the \strutbox to not inherit a situation which
% could go through unmodified but would depend upon the sequence
% of earlier font changes, if you didn't make the change now.
%
           \setbox\strutbox\hbox{\vrule
               \@height.7\baselineskip 
               \@depth.3\baselineskip
               \@width\z@}%
           \ifdim\ht\igor@tempbox>\ht\strutbox
% comment out these two lines in real use cases
    \typeout{IGOR: MODIFYING DEFAULT STRUTBOX\on@line.}%
    \typeout{IGOR: old=\the\ht\strutbox, new=\the\ht\igor@tempbox}%
           \setbox\strutbox\hbox{\vrule
               \@height\ht\igor@tempbox % add some extra? 
               \@depth\dimexpr\baselineskip-\ht\igor@tempbox\relax
               \@width\z@}\fi }%


\expandafter\def
  \csname selectfont \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \endcsname
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  {\csname selectfont \endcsname\igor@fixstrutbox}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}\thispagestyle{empty}

Without struts (no problems):
\begin{multicols}{2}
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit\par
\columnbreak
État de droit État de droit État de droit État de droit État
de droit État de droit État de droit\par
\end{multicols}

With struts: (careful to put a strut also on left first line.)

\begin{multicols}{2}
\strut Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit\par
\columnbreak
\strut État de droit État de droit État de droit État de droit État
de droit État de droit État de droit\par
\end{multicols}

\Large

Changed size. 
\begin{multicols}{2}
\strut Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat\par\hrule
\columnbreak
\strut État de droit État de droit État de droit \strut État de droit État
de droit État de droit État de droit\par\hrule
\end{multicols}

\sffamily

Other font.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\strut Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit
Etat de droit Etat de droit Etat de droit\par\hrule
\columnbreak
\strut État de droit État de droit État de droit \strut État de droit État
de droit État de droit État de droit\par\hrule
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Log (with `\igor@fixstrutbox` containing only `É`, and that was with an earlier version of the code):

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
IGOR: MODIFYING DEFAULT STRUTBOX on input line 30.
IGOR: old=10.14995pt, new=11.004pt
IGOR: MODIFYING DEFAULT STRUTBOX on input line 51.
IGOR: old=15.39993pt, new=15.68199pt
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmss on input line 62.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd
File: t1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
IGOR: MODIFYING DEFAULT STRUTBOX on input line 73.
IGOR: old=10.14995pt, new=11.004pt
```

Switch to `sans serif` caused no adjustment, but if `\igor@fixstrutbox` is set-up with `\hbox{ĂÉÈÅ}` rather, one gets (again with earlier code, not re-compiled).

```
IGOR: MODIFYING DEFAULT STRUTBOX on input line 30.
IGOR: old=10.14995pt, new=11.004pt
IGOR: MODIFYING DEFAULT STRUTBOX on input line 51.
IGOR: old=15.39993pt, new=15.68199pt
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmss on input line 62.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd
File: t1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
IGOR: MODIFYING DEFAULT STRUTBOX on input line 62.
IGOR: old=15.68199pt, new=15.97498pt
IGOR: MODIFYING DEFAULT STRUTBOX on input line 73.
IGOR: old=10.14995pt, new=11.004pt
```

The same with only `\hbox{Ă}` showing that this character is taller in sans serif than `É` at least in `\Large` font size.

I have edited the `\igor@fixstrutbox` to always reset first the `\strutbox` to the default LaTeX definition, because if not the decision to keep the `\strutbox` or modify it would depend on the history of earlier font changes, as LaTeX calls only in certain circumstances `\set@fontsize` which gives non `\relax` meaning to `\size@update` (executed by `\selectfont`). I have not updated the image and logs above after that change.

Comment: What should be changed in your examples to make them appear properly (with lmodern) ? Do you know a free NNTP server for fr.comp.text.tex? The link, which you gave, has broken encoding in browser and I would like to read it in a newsreader application (like pan).

Comment: you could try `nntp.aioe.org` which even works on port `80` (useful when only `html` connections are allowed). For posting to it I am not sure, my Thunderbird is configure to use the `smtp` server of my Internet provider. Yes, I noticed that the link I gave has broken encoding. Will try to find an alternative one.

Comment: here is a [better link](http://fr.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/TXN8cIQM/pb-d-alignement-avec-minipage-et-capitale-accentuees) for the thread on `fr.comp.text.tex` dating back to January 2013. I wanted initially to post such a link, but for some reason the search on `narkive.com` did not work on my browser. After having found it on the dubious other site, I knew the date and the title of the thread, thus could load more and more posts until going back to the right time.

Comment: My examples are fixed via either 1) not use `\strut`'s in such places or 2) modify the definition of `\strutbox` inside `\set@fontsize` (if using `LaTeX`).

Comment: Please give a full example how to modify `\set@fontsize` in LaTeX.

Comment: the displayed log has line numbers a bit off, because I modified source code afterwards.

Comment: my proposed patch assumes `\baselineskip` itself to be at least as big as the height of the characters used in the `\igor@tempbox`. If not the depth of the `\strut` will be zero and its height will be the height of  the material inside `\igor@tempbox`. My code caters only for ascenders: if the `\strut` is used in a line with a character having a big descender, and if the `\strut` now has a height too big to fit together with the big descender we will be in the `\lineskip` situation again.

Comment: I agree with the news thread - \strut is a hack. It should be possible to do without strut in all situations where we need strut. I think I understand where the problem lies: the computation for the interline glue between the two boxes is done purely by looking at their heights and depths, and if a rule is added at top or bottom - the depth of the box will be zero and everything else will be added to the height. For example, \halign is equivalent to \vbox{\hbox...\hbox...}. In ruled table examples in TeXbook \strut is used, and \offinterlineskip is issued to kill all interline glue insertion.

Comment: So a way out of this would be to make the \hbox'es "transparent" for interline glue computations somehow (in Lua this is probably possible) - as a way to do without \strut.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing another answer, which exploits a feature of `XeTeX`, its parameter `\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics`. The idea is the following:

```
\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics 0
```

and all character boxes will have identical heights and depths. Set the height of the strutbox to this common height, and its depth to the value needed so that the sum of the two add up to `\baselineskip`.

Then you can reset

```
\XeTeXuseglypmetrices 1
```

for the default boxes.

This is illustrated by the `xetex` code below. It containes a `\fbox` macro which frames its material adding no extra height or depth or width. The `\TEST` macro is supposed to display some such boxes, containing characters and struts, or only  a strut, or also normal characters and a `\vrule`. We see most of the time `lineskip` glue added because always height + depth exceeds baselineskip if we find an accented letter and a strut (the strut has too big a depth).

Then at bottom we set up a better strut, and see that there no more extra vertical interline spaces. This final step done with "Times New Roman" which is a system font on my Mac.

[image]

forgot the code:

```
\newdimen\fboxrule
\fboxrule 0.4pt

\def\mycolor {rgb 0 0 1}
\def\fbox #1{\leavevmode
              {\special{color push \mycolor}%
              \hbox{\vtop{\vbox{%
              \hrule height \fboxrule
              \kern -\fboxrule
              \hbox{\vrule width \fboxrule\kern-\fboxrule
                    \special{color pop}%
                    #1%
                    \special{color push \mycolor}%
                    \kern-\fboxrule\vrule width \fboxrule}%
              }\kern-\fboxrule
              \hrule height\fboxrule}}%
              \special{color pop}%
              }%
}

\def\TEST {\noindent
     \fbox{\strut\kern1cm
    {\def\mycolor{rgb 1 0 0 }\fbox {A}\fbox{E}\fbox{C}\fbox{gg}%
                 \kern1cm\strut}}
     ABCD
     \fbox{\strut\kern.5cm\strut}
     \vrule height\ht\strutbox
            depth \dp\strutbox

     \noindent
    \fbox{\strut\kern1cm
    {\def\mycolor{rgb 1 0 0 }\fbox {A}\fbox{É}\fbox{Ç}\fbox{gg}%
                 \kern1cm\strut}}
     ABCD
     \fbox{\strut\kern.5cm\strut}
     \vrule height\ht\strutbox
            depth \dp\strutbox
     \par
      }

\font\lmfont=rm-lmr10

\lmfont

Latin Modern

\the\ht\strutbox, \the\dp\strutbox, \the\baselineskip

\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=1

\TEST

\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=0

\TEST

\font\times="Times New Roman"

\times

Times New Roman

\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=1

\TEST

\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=0

\TEST

\setbox0\hbox{A}\the\ht0, \the\dp0, common height plus depth of strut=
\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp\strutbox\relax, bigger than
\the\baselineskip

With better strut:

\setbox\strutbox\hbox{\vrule height\ht0
                             depth\dimexpr\baselineskip-\ht0\relax}

\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=0

\TEST

\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=1

\TEST

\nopagenumbers
\bye
```

Comment: Why with Latin Modern `\XeTeXuseglyphmetrics=0` does not work?

Comment: I don't know. I observed it yesterday, even briefly thought about asking the question on `xetex` dev list, but figured I should first read more of the manual. Then I forgot. Possibly the feature works only for OpenType fonts.

Comment: I have an idea how to get rid of the `\strut` problem - it is necessary to lower the accents a little bit. The same problem was solved in CS-fonts. See my question here (the first one, before the edit): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275218/how-to-compile-lm-fonts-from-sources. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko no  I don't. If lowered accents are aesthetically pleasing, then perhaps indeed it is worthwhile to go through the whole thing; but the `\strut` problem in itself can be cured more easily as in my answers. The problem with the `\strut` is that it seems to be designed with too big a depth. One may also argue that glyphs should not have a depth; the collisions are argued to be rare, and the `TeX` solution to separate more the lines is bad as it acts globally on a local problem. Ideally one  (luatex?) perhaps should move horizontally the glyphs when a collision is detected.