# How to compile LM-fonts from sources?

Tags: fonts

Suppose we need to go all the way from METAType1 sources for LM-fonts

http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download/lm2004mt1.zip

up to these two files: `lmr10.pfb` and `rm-lmr10.tfm`

Can anybody give some tips or recommendations for further reading on how to achieve this?

Comment: Ask GUST: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

Comment: They are available from GUST as @egreg observes: see http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download. That might be an answer: not sure (seems perhaps too obvious).

Comment: @JosephWright: I hoped somebody already did something similar and will share a complete step-by-step example how to change the glyph which I specified in the example. I cannot find instructions how to change what I need and recompile from scratch...

Comment: Al: I don't see that this is OT at all! What's the issue with the question?

Comment: The question has changed and now it is interesting.

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb24-1/jackowski.pdf) and [this one](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb27-0/jackowski.pdf) would be helpful. Note that there is not a 1-1 relationship between `.pfb` and`.tfm` files as there is between `.pfb` and `.afm` files, for example.

Comment: @cfr: In the first link it's just common phrases - no specific explanation of the core process of compiling. The most relevant parts from it are: "... METAType1 sources that can be maintained — adjusted, augmented, improved ... it is relatively simple to modify existing sources..." The second link is more interesting...

Comment: It depends what you know and where you're starting. I don't know what you know or where you're starting, so I posted both ;).

Comment: @cfr: In the second document the info seems outdated: it is said about `mpe` file, but `sel` file is used now instead. Also, in current sources there is `pfcommon.dat`, which is not described in the second link. And `pfcommon` does not occur in any file from the bundle, so it is not clear how it is used...

Comment: I said it might be helpful. I am not sure that you are going to find a step-by-step guide for this. (Unless somebody writes one as an answer.) If you don't find it helpful, I'm afraid I've wasted your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have the required programs installed (metapost, gawk and t1utils), and regardless of your OS or TeX distro, the following should work:

1. Dump the contents of the Latin Modern sources *and* [metatype1](http://ctan.org/pkg/metatype1) in the same directory.
2. Go to the working directory, start a shell session, and copy the file `e-rm.mp` into `lm-tex.mpe`.
3. Enter an interactive session of metapost: `mpost -jobname=lmr10`. Once inside, type `\relax` to enter interactive mode. then issue the statements `generating:=0; input lmr10`.
4. That should generate all the glyphs and get you back to the shell. Once there, process the output files (`lmr10.*`) with the following commands.

`gawk -f mp2pf.awk -vCD=pfcommon.dat -vNAME=lmr10
gawk -f packsubr.awk -vVERBOSE=1 -vLEV=5 -vOUP=lmr10.pn lmr10.p
t1asm -b lmr10.pn lmr10.pfb`

5. To generate the `tfm` file, run step (3) with `-jobname=rm-lmr10` and `generating:=1;` instead.

Metatype1 includes the batch files `mkfont1.bat`, `mkt1.bat` and `mktfm.bat` that should do the job on windows; in fact, I got all the instructions from those scripts. You may try to translate the scripts for [b|a]sh.

Comment: For the first part of the question it works - `pfb` file is produced, which is great. But no `tfm`...

Comment: It is not the same which `tftopl rm-lmr10` produces in TeX Live. Notably, the generated `tfm` is lacking "LIGTABLE"...

Comment: it works now, but with `qx-` encoding, instead of `rm-`

Comment: In your command there is missing `mpout.afm`. Using `pltotf rm-mpout` gives errors; `vptovf rm-mpout.vpl` works. Still, the pl file is not the same which `tftopl rm-lmr10` produces. How to specify encoding *properly* in step 3?

Comment: In the sources there is `e-rm.sel`, so the answer remains incomplete. The ultimate test must be the (almost) zero difference between `tftopl rm-lmr10` and `tftopl mpout.tfm`.

Comment: I found a hint: "...in order to generate a TeX font metrics with a given encoding, the respective encoding file should be placed in the current directory and renamed to lm-tex.mpe; otherwise a default encoding (QX) will be used..."

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. One final problem to resolve: take for example `CHARACTER O 375` - in system it has "CHARHT R 0.688875", in generated it has "CHARHT R 0.0".  In reality this glyph is "ý", which cannot have zero height. Do you get the same results?

Comment: indeed: there are subtle differences throughout the two files... the heights seem to be systematically wrong...

Comment: I think it's worth to see which slots "misbehave" and try to establish a pattern between them, which may give an idea why they are generated incorrectly...

Comment: But the rm-lmr10.tfm in the distribution does exist, nevertheless. You cannot argue that.

Comment: The `rm-lmr10.tfm` exists, thus there does exist some sequence of commands which leads to it. This is what the question is all about.

Comment: @erreka: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Comment: @IgorLiferenko You shouldn't end up needing `vptvf` because Latin Modern does not use virtual fonts at all. It is all done with `.tfm`. Also, you cannot, in general, expect a perfect match in the `.pl` you produce and one you get from running `tftopl`. If I generate a `.pl` file and then run `pltotf` followed by `tftopl` I will not get back an identical file. That said, the metrics for the glyphs should match, at least to a reasonable approximation.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Yes, I know. I just meant that you can't expect the files to be almost identical in any case. Obviously it is wrong if the metrics are giving the height of letters as zero. But even if the metrics were correct, the files might still differ significantly in other ways. That is, that the files differ is not just in itself evidence of a bug. In this case, it is the nature of the differences which constitutes evidence of the bug i.e. you have to look at the content of the differences.

Comment: @cfr: It is not clear what you mean - please explain with an example.

Comment: @cfr if you compile, say, cmr10 from sources with metafont, you expect to get the same tfm consistently; we found that modern metapost not only does not produce the same tfm for lmr10, but it also fails to produce the tfm correctly.

Comment: @erreka Yes. But the process of going from `.pl` to `.tfm` and back to `.pl` does not necessarily take you back to an identical file. *Of course*, the metrics should not differ in any significant way. But that does not guarantee an identical `.pl`. `.pl` files can differ in other ways. Depending on how the `.pl` file is produced, it may contain information which will be stripped by the conversion process. In that case, that information is lost. Converting the `.tfm` back to `.pl` will not restore it and the file will not be the one you started with.

Comment: @erreka The *files* will not be the same. At least theoretically, the code should be effectively the same. But PL -> TFM -> PL will not necessarily get you a file much like the one you started with. (If you `diff`, for example.) This is expected: `pltotf` strips elements which make the `.pl` more readable for human beings but which TeX doesn't need. At least, this is how it has always worked for me.

Comment: @cfr: Committed revision 2073.

Comment: Is there a way to regenerate the otf files for Latin Modern? I would like to generate blacker versions so that the prints look better on paper. MathJax does exactly that, through the use of FontForge, however, in MathJax the Latin Modern otf is chopped into many pieces, which is not what I am after, and I cannot really understand how to generate a single file from the scripts at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-dev/tree/master/fonts/OTF/TeX ---any comments, tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Ekin: that's a different question. You should open a new question separately. I think you could adjust the thickness directly on the MetaPost sources, without going through FontForge, but I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: @erreka I just opened a new question where I provide more information on what I would like to do: [How to compile thicker OTF version of Latin Modern fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460517/how-to-compile-thicker-otf-version-of-latin-modern-fonts)