# What is this rendering style

Tags: rendering

Below is a picture comparing the default overleaf rendering (top) and the rendering of a book (John M. Howie - Complex Analysis) (bottom).

How can I mimic the bottom rendering? Is it a product of a specific latex compiler, is it because of the way the pdf was saved etc, or is it something else? Any ideas are appreciated.

[image: John M. Howie Complex Analysis]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)

Comment: One indication may be the publication date of the book.  If it's the early 1980s, most available printers weren't very high resolution, so the type could look heavier, even if the font was named the same.

Comment: Where did you get the second image? It looks nice. Btw, the pdf rendering can depend on the OS as well. I see that the text in Preview on MacOS looks considerably thicker compared to Edge/Adobe on Windows or Okular/Evince on Linux, on the same machine and monitor.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100577/fatter-computer-modern

Comment: And also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225027/how-to-create-new-font-which-is-thicker-version-of-computer-modern

Comment: Possibly https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460517/how-to-compile-thicker-otf-version-of-latin-modern-fonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Fatter Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100577/fatter-computer-modern) the suggestion to use the `mlmodern` package, which provides (according to its manual) a "sturdy rendition of the Computer Modern design".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\begin{document}
\section{The Heine-Borel Theorem}
The rather technical Heine-Borel Theorem is necessary for some of our proofs.

By an \textbf{open covering} of a set $S$ we mean a possibly infinite collection
\[
\mathcal{C} = \{V_i:i\in I\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Screenshot with the default font and with `mlmodern`:

[image]